# leaves are falling off amaryllis, is this natural or do I cut them off?\

Tags: leaves, amaryllis

I have an amaryllis that's leaves have started to fall, only one is left still standing, is this natural, do I cut them off?  Thank you so much.

Comment: We need more info - and a photo would be helpful. For example: Where are you in the world? Are you new to growing amaryllis (was the bulb a gift)? Did you put the amaryllis outside recently? Is it in the ground or in a container? If in a container, are there drainage holes? How often have you been watering? If outside, is it in full sun, part sun, or shade? If inside, what orientation is the window it's sitting behind?